# How can I get a list of all the com+ components of a com+ application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, .net-4.0, com+

I am trying to work with COM+ using c# and ASP.NET.  I have been following an [example](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/complus/article.php/c3943/COM-Automation-Using-COMAdminCatalog-in-NET-C.htm), however part of it fails.

```
dynamic oCatalog = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ComAdmin.COMAdminCatalog"));
/* Get the Applications collection and populate it */
dynamic applicationInstances = oCatalog.GetCollection("Applications");
applicationInstances.Populate();
foreach (dynamic applicationInstance in applicationInstances)
    {
        Response.Write("<p>" + applicationInstance.Name.ToString() + "-" + applicationInstance.Key.ToString() + "</p>");
        dynamic objComponents = oCatalog.GetCollection("Components", applicationInstance.Key);
        objComponents.Populate();
        foreach(dynamic Components in objComponents)
        {
            Response.Write("<p>" + Components.Name.ToString() + "</p>");
        }           
    }
```

When the above call oCatalog.GetCollection("Components", applicationInstance.Key) is called I get the error:

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Error while invoking
>   GetCollection.

How can I get a list of the current components in an application instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to ask the "applications" collection for the components for an specific application:

```
ICOMAdminCatalog2 oCatalog = (ICOMAdminCatalog2) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ComAdmin.COMAdminCatalog"));

ICatalogCollection applications = oCatalog.GetCollection("Applications");
applications.Populate();
foreach (ICatalogObject applicationInstance in applications)
{
    ICatalogCollection comps = applications.GetCollection("Components", applicationInstance.Key);
    comps.Populate();
    foreach (ICatalogObject comp in comps)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", comp.Name, comp.Key);
    }
}
```

for an example check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686093(v=vs.85).aspx